# Have you noticed performance gains by compiling Apache and MySQL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

So I'm sitting here debating whether or not to just `apt-get install` Apache2 and MySQL or spend a day compiling them from source. My main motivation for compiling would be to improve performance. Another motivation would be to circumvent the "Debian way," but I guess I can live with it if I must.

My websites are moderately busy, but nothing too crazy. VPS hosting.

So in your experience, is there a noticeable performance gain from compiling from source or would I be spinning my wheels?

P.S. I already compiled PHP from source because I didn't like the "Debian way."

Comment: So you are going to waste your life running the compile cycle for each security update, aren't you? You also have to consider testing the effect of all the updates on your production environment, both in terms of performance and compatibility.

Comment: My question is about performance, nothing else. If I couldn't handle compiling and testing, I wouldn't have asked. Downvoters, this ain't Reddit. Karma's a beyotch!

Comment: To downvoters: the question is legit.

Comment: I'm not sure in the context of the [faq] it is a legitimate question, it's too open ended.  Someone might say yes, another person might say no.  It's verging on a discussion about the benefits of rolling your own vs. distribution.  Just my 2c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I have not noticed any appreciable performance gains that way. Much more performance is gained the usual way: profiling, refactoring for speed, caching and the other usual tricks.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing your experience. All of the answers and comments here have helped me come to my senses. Thanks to all!

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with all the other answers about sticking to repo packages. If you're willing and able to invest the time in maintaining your own packages, and have a good reason to do so, then go for it. I wouldn't do it for speed alone though, but I have a repo of 1000 perl packages because we roll our own, updated perl and stick it all in /usr/local so we don't interfere with the system perl.

Answer (score 1):

Most people here will advise you to stick with the packages supplied by your distro. This is because you get the benefit of patches/bug fixes and compatibility/dependency management.

If you roll your own then you have to take responsibility for all of these issues and you loose herd immunity. We see lots of questions from people who have stepped outside of their  distro's packange management system and have ended up in a complete mess.

Stick with the Debian way (in some ways) You know it makes sense.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with rolling my own. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some very specific need, don't bother.

Don't underestimate what you get for free using the OS packages:

- No need to monitor the upstream community for security notices
- No need to rebuild your stack whenever there's an update
- No need to maintain your own build environment ... because you'll need to build your own packages, right? How else will you back out if thing go wrong

You're more likely to get big performance gains from tuning the stack you have. E.g.,

- Use a CDN for static assets
- Switching to php-fpm + nginx will likely give you easy gains
- Caching layer such as varnish
- Php-apc and/or caching app data in memcache
- DB memory allocation, indices, etc.

Comment: Loading something that's been tested vs running on what's essentially a beta test. Been there, the wasted time makes up for any slight performance increase. After I switched to Debian Stable, I never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

## Should you roll your own?

[image]

The usual answer is: **NO**.

## Where do performance gains come from?

- better tuning (see [Dennis Kaarsemaker](https://serverfault.com/a/514504/140016)'s and [chrskly](https://serverfault.com/a/514507/140016)'s answers);
- changes in stack (again, [chrskly](https://serverfault.com/a/514507/140016)'s answer));
- better algorithms.

**Algorithms** and **stack structure** set the maximum attainable performance, while **tuning** helps you get to that maximum under your local load etc. conditions. To get better algorithms, you have to become a developer - and it takes a lot of time and effort.

Note that compiling doesn't figure in this list (unless you are meddling with configure options - which sometimes makes sense - and even then rolling the `.deb` file trumps the straightforward old-fashioned tarballing-making-make installing).

## When does compiling from the source make sense?

Here I assume that you use Debian's packaging system (including such goodies as [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)), otherwise you are in for a bloodletting down the line.

- As a training exercise.
- When dealing with in-house developers (although if you do it on a permanent basis something's wrong in your job description).
- While getting ready to become a developer.
- When your dev team is proficient enough to make custom patches to the server software.

A word of caution: fiddling with MySQL for performance is not worth it. Install (or even buy and install) a better RDBMS instead.

My 2 cents, anyway.

Comment: +1 for the graphic, effort and comment to downvoters!

Comment: No, do *not* use checkinstall. Learn how to build packages properly!

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker - agreed.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Is there a difference between FPM and Checkinstall? Both seem to be cross-repo package generators

Comment: @TheLQ - fpm doesn't require root privileges during build, checkinstall does. fpm works with python, php, ruby, npm packages, compiles into Debian packages etc.

Comment: Never used fpm, so I can't say. I always build proper packages, writing debian/* or *.spec by hand, following a template and understanding what is actually going on.